# How to require an external js library in Node.js with a typescript declaration file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a Node.js project written in Typescript and I am trying to get it to work with mime.js (https://github.com/broofa/node-mime). I have a declaration file (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mime/mime.d.ts) but cannot get node.js in typescript to work nicely with it.

I have the following:

```
/// <reference path="../../libs/mime.d.ts" />

import mime = require( 'mime' );
```

This keeps the type script compiler happy and all is good until I try to run it in Node.

When I try to run it I get

```
Cannot find module 'mime'
```

However, if I edit the generated javascript to the following:

```
import mime = require( '../../libs/mime' );
```

It all works fine. If I change the typescript file to have the require with the relative path I get a compiler error:

```
Cannot find external module '../../libs/mime'
```

How do I refer Typescript to both the mime.d.ts file and to the mime.js file so that both the compiler and Node are happy.

Many Thanks

Comment: What version of TypeScript are you using?

Comment: Typescript version 1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better way of doing this that works with node_modules folders and typings folder. A working example can be seen here:

https://github.com/Roaders/contact-list-checker/tree/external-js-module-example

In this app I import the csv js library in the ContactList class:

```
import csv = require('csv');
```

This is after installing it:

```
npm install csv
```

as the csv lib is in the node_modules folder we do not need to specify and path to the lib and just csv is sufficient for the compiler to find it. Without a d.ts declaration file we get errors though. This declaration file could be located in the typings folder and come directly from tsd but this lib is not found on tsd so I had to create my own. csv.d.ts is in libs/csv:

```
declare module "csv" {}
```

(I will add function interfaces to this later)

the module name HAS to match the import name. The filename can be anything.
You can add a reference to this file in the file that's doing the import:

```
///<reference path="../../../libs/csv/csv.d.ts" />
```

or as I have done you can just add a reference to it in the tsconfig.json in the root of the project:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "diagnostics": true
    },
    "files": [
        "./app.ts",
        "./typings/tsd.d.ts",
        "./libs/libs.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

(where libs.d.ts has a reference to csv.d.ts)

This method allows you to install js libs using npm install and use declarations from tsd.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript supports relative paths only for TypeScript modules. Ambient JavaScript modules should be placed in `node_modules` folder. From [Node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders):

> If the module identifier passed to require() is not a native module, and does not begin with '/', '../', or './', then node starts at the parent directory of the current module, and adds /node_modules, and attempts to load the module from that location.

### Workaround 1

Place `.d.ts` next to `.js` module and change it from:

```
declare module "mime" {
   ...
}
```

to:

```
declare module Mime {
   ...
}
export = Mime;
```

### Workaround 2

Rewrite `.d.ts` files from:

```
declare module "mime" {
    export function lookup(path: string): string;
    ...
}
```

to:

```
declare interface IMime {
    function lookup(path: string): string;
    ...
}
```

And then use plain `var` instead of `import`:

```
var mime = <IMime>require( '../../libs/mime' );
```

Comment: Workaround 1 worked great thanks. I didn't want to use npm to install it in a magically created folder as then every other developer would have to do the same (unless I check in the modules folder but didn't like the idea of that). Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: in the root of the project 'npm install mime'. It will create the node_modules directory with mime inside of it. You can import it by 'require('mime')'. You also have to 'reference' the .d.ts file but that's the minor thing, with the npm package node will be able to import the actual javascript lib.

I also recommend using TSD ('npm install tsd -g') for getting the .d.ts files from DefinitelyTyped.

Btw sry for typos, I'm writing from mobile.

Answer (score 0):

you need:

1. Add definitions file(*.d.ts) of the library
2. You must understand, the definition file contains only the interfaces of the library. You should be add the library source code separately.

References:

The typescript definitions:
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped

The definitions for mime:
https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/mime/mime.d.ts